# AngularJS validation issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a few issues regarding validation in AngularJS

**Issue 1:**

How do i achieve the following in AngularJS in the controller **not** the view

*vanilla js code*

```
document.getElementById('InputId).value.length
```

i tried the following in AngularJS

```
$scope.myForm.InputngModelName.length
```

**Issue 2**

I have a `directive` that validates an email

How do i call it from my controller?

Following is the directive

```
angular.module('myValidator',[])
    .directive('myValidator',function(){
            return{
                restrict: 'A',
                require: "ngModel",
                link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl){
                    switch (attrs.myValidator){
                        case 'email':
                            var regex=/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/;
                            break;
                    }
                    ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue){
                        if(regex.test(viewValue)){
                            ctrl.$setValidity('myValidator',true);
                        }
                        else{
                            ctrl.$setValidity('myValidator',false);
                        }
                        return viewValue;
                    });
                }
            };
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look into using angular-validator, it is very lean and you can easily add custom validation methods. It includes an email validator as well.

Angular-Validator is an easy to use, powerful and lightweight AngularJS validation directive.

```
<input  type = "email"
                            name = "emailAddress"
                            class = "form-control"
                            ng-model = "form.emailAddress"
                            invalid-message="'Thats not a real email address'"
                            required-message="'Yo this is required'"
                            validate-on="dirty"
                            required>
```

https://github.com/turinggroup/angular-validator
http://plnkr.co/edit/XbDYKrM2QUf8g1ubTHma?p=preview

Comment: Looks interesting, i am "bowering" it now, can it `validate-on="Globalvar==true"` ?

Comment: Yes you should be able to set validate-on="customFunction" and a whole lot more. It leaned out my validation code, both HTML and controller. Made my validation life very easy.

Comment: correction: validate-on can only have, blur or dirty, if you read the documentation. You will want to do a custom validate method and add your dependency response there.